# Javascript / OpenLayers Matching

Tags: javascript, openlayers, matching

I used to filter my features using:

```
for (var i=0; i<features.length; i++) 
 { 
 if (features[i].attributes.color == 'blue') 
. 
.
```

but sometimes the value could be: dark blue, light blue .. etc 
So I used match but still can't get it work:

```
var x = "blue"; 
 if (features[i].attributes.color.match(new RegExp(x, "ig")))
```

I get this error:

```
Cannot call method 'match' of undefined
```

Comment: Did you check if `features[i]` exists?

Comment: yes.. and it works if i use `(features[i].attributes.color == 'blue')`

Comment: still get `Cannot call method 'toString' of undefined `

Comment: re-check your features array. Use the script console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that some of features doesn't have color attribute set. Run, for example:

```
for (var i=0; i<features.length; i++) 
    console.log(typeof features[i].attributes.color);
```

You CAN use == on undefined attribute, but you can't run function on it, that explains, why `==  'blue'` doesn't throw error.

```
var foo = {bar: 'Test'};
// That doesn't throw error
if (foo.baz == 'blue') console.log('Is blue');
// And that throws error
if (foo.baz.match(new RegExp('blue', 'ig'))) console.log('Is blue');
```

So you should test at first, whether color attribute is set, then test it:

```
for (var i=0; i<features.length; i++) 
    if (features[i].attributes.color && features[i].attributes.color == 'blue') ...
```